# How to search with find above your directory?

Tags: bash, find, cd

A part of the script make this:

```
dir_year=2017
dir_archive=/home/user/Documents/0_@Archivo
bindir=/home/user/bin
filework=out.txt

find "$dir_archive/$dir_year/" -name *.md > ${bindir}/${filework}
```

But it gives me an error since find does not look in top directories. The script is `in/home/user/Documents/0_ @ File/2017/script-directory`.

For it to work I have to do:

```
cd "$dir_archive/$dir_year/"
find "$dir_archive/$dir_year/" -name *.md > ${bindir}/${filework}
```

Is there any way I do not need the cd command?

Thanks

Comment: The first response works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be:

```
-name '*.md'
```

otherwise `*.md` would be expanded by the shell